# elastic search + couchdb OR sphinx + mysql .... for document review SaaS

Tags: mysql, nosql, couchdb, sphinx, elasticsearch

I HAVE:

Set of pre-processed office documents (Word, Excel, PDFs, Emails, Power Points, etc.) provided as "Load Files" (approx. 2-4 terabytes per set)

"LOAD FILES" CONSIST OF:

1. Single pg tiffs (printed from the office documents.. a 15 page word
   doc would have 15 tiffs)
2. Meta data extracted from the office documents presented in a delimited .dat file which includes the full text.
3. .log file which associates the .tiff & .dat (.dat & .log files put together comprise about 7-10% of the data set size)
4. Original office documents

USERS VIA BROWSERS WILL:

1. Do a variety of keyword searches in the full text & meta data found in the .dat
2. View the tiff images and occasionally the original office doc
3. Classify each document with some user defined label and sometimes make notes
4. Sort the data in a variety of ways... eg date sent, author, subject etc

TRYING TO DECIDE BETWEEN:
elastic search + couchdb OR sphinx + mysql

I've been advised that search will be the primary engineering issue so decided to use that as a base for determining everything else.

With future growth in mind I figured I would choose all things "cloud".  I keyed in on elastic search which I read pairs well with couchdb (no particular reason beyond the advertised tight integration with ES)... along with symfony2 + doctrine (not married to these but read they pair well with ES) instead of zend.

But then someone remarked that the data seems very well structured so sphinx/mysql is a better path with sphinx "out of the box" split by nodes for the cloud.

CONTEXT:

My main goal is speed and performance of the searches & serving up of the tiff images.  Scalability is a secondary concern as the amount of users could grow to the tens of thousands..... perhaps 100k but not "web scale" (tens of millions).  However some of these users would be on the application 8hrs a day.

QUESTION:

For this particular app do you feel elastic search + nosql is overkill in the sense that it will require more time/complexity/resources to configure than what I really need with no significant performance advantage?  Or will sphinx mysql eventually be a bottle neck with larger data sets/more users?

Answer (score 1):

Intended as a comment more than an answer... (was too long though)

I cant really comment on couchdb, but I thought I'd share my thoughts about MySQL/Sphinx.

Firstly, searching is blisteringly fast, even with complex criteria.
Some aspects of the index need to be stored in RAM. If you have a huge dataset you will need to allocate sufficient resources to Sphinx in order to get this performance.

A potential downside to Sphinx, is that in my experience 'sphinx out the box' only happens when you have fairly simple requirements. 
If you want to preprocess documents prior to indexing (ie run regexp's on document, substitute forum bbcodes etc), then it becomes a lot more complex (in my case I have to index using XMLPIPE2, instead of Sphinx talking direct to mysql).

Another potential problem with Sphinx is that whilst there are real-time indices, they are not yet (IMO) a mature feature, and have some limitations too. 
Consequently you may need to reindex the dataset periodically (or more likely, index the bits that are new, then merge them into the main index - called a main + delta). This isnt necessarily a problem, but again its one more moving part.

"My main goal is speed and performance of the searches" -- Sphinx will not disappoint you here, and it will scale very well.